# Any pointers on cross correlation functions in C/Java/C++

Tags: java

I am working on a project which would require implementing functionalities like cross correlation. Can anyone help me if there are any open source API/libraries existing.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Apache Math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/). 
http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/stat.html
shows:

> The org.apache.commons.math3.stat.correlation package computes
>   covariances and correlations for pairs of arrays or columns of a
>   matrix. Covariance computes covariances, PearsonsCorrelation provides
>   Pearson's Product-Moment correlation coefficients and
>   SpearmansCorrelation computes Spearman's rank correlation.

There is also the older [JAMA library](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/).